# My account dissapeard

Tags: pokemon-go

I just updated the new version and evolved some pokemons, got to level 21 while having a lucky egg active. Lost the gps connection and had sto start over the game (as happens now and then), but now my account is suddenly gone! I opened the game and came to the start page with my email and passwords and the professor intro and how to choose my avatar! Where is my account and all my pokemons and level 21?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can fix this by logging in using a different account, then logging out and logging back in using your regular account.

I'm not sure but I've also heard that if your original account is a Google account, you have to create a trainer club account and log in using that, then log back out and log in using your standard account.

These are just some solutions I ran across some time ago, so I'm not sure if they work.